# Short date format in email templates

Tags: magento-1.8

We have a long date format in the transitional emails, such as "2015/12/01 00:00..." and I would like to show the date in a short format, like dd/mm/YYYY only. The email variable is:

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}
```

If I put "short" instead of "long", does it work?

Comment: Have you tried it? It's not like you're testing nuclear launch codes... change it and see what happens.

Comment: Actually I haven't tried, but I guess always there is someone who tried before and that could save your time!